# Oracle string in DB larger than on UI

Tags: asp.net, database, string, oracle, encoding

There is a string, which comes from text field, and has 200 character limit. Field in oracle DB's table has a maximum value of 200 characters. Application crashes, saying it can't write 212 characters to a field of maximum 200 characters. Problem is clearly on DB level, as on the other database with identical table and CRUD, it all goes well.

Suspecting that problem might be in encoding differences, I made a

`SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;`

on both databases. Results are identical, `NLS_CHARACTERSET` in both cases show value of  `AL32UTF8`. What might be the problem?

P.S. It's ASP.NET application, if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If also NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter is the same, maybe the columns are defined differenty: VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) vs VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)?

HTH.

Alessandro